# Check if NaT changes to datetime and update value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following data frames.

df_1:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-01
456        NaT
789        2020-10-10
135        2020-05-31
234        NaT
111        NaT
```

df_2:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-02
456        2021-01-01
789        2020-10-11
135        2020-6-01
```

The output should capture anytime the date changes to a date in the future from the previous entry and/or when NaT changes to a new date.

new_df should equal:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-02
456        2021-01-01
789        2020-10-11
135        2020-6-01
```

What I have tried:

```
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_1['date'])
df_2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_2['date'])
s = df_2.set_index('order_id')['date']

mapped = df_1['order_id'].map(s)
mask = mapped > df_1['date']
df_1.loc[mask, 'date'] = mapped
```

This is only giving changes when the date is changed to a future date but it is not capturing anytime NaT becomes a new date.

Comment: Your resulting data frame is the exact copy of df_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use np.where after coercing the dates to datetime.

```
import numpy as np
df_1['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_1['date'])
df_2['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_2['date'])
df=pd.merge(df_2,df_1, how='left', on='order_id',suffixes=('_left', ''))
df=df.assign(date=np.where(df['date'].isna()|df['date_left'].sub(df['date']).dt.days.gt(0),df['date_left'],df['date'])).drop('date_left',1)



  order_id       date
0       123 2020-01-02
1       456 2021-01-01
2       789 2020-10-11
3       135 2020-06-01
```

Comment: Sorry I just made an edit, will this solution take into consideration when NaT remains the same between the two data frames? If you look at my last edit you'll see that I add order_id 234,111 these should not carry over the new_df @wwnde

Comment: Can edit the answer. It will require complete change of method. We need to merge

Comment: My apologies there, I realize my example wasn't complete but that is what I am looking to accomplish. I really appreciate the insight here!

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look here shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge`, which subsets to only those orders that might have been updated then check if the date is later, or if it was null then filled, and use that to subset the merged result.

```
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date'])
df_2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['date'])

res = df_1.merge(df_2, on='order_id', suffixes=['_orig', ''])
#   order_id  date_orig       date
#0       123 2020-01-01 2020-01-02
#1       456        NaT 2021-01-01
#2       789 2020-10-10 2020-10-11
#3       135 2020-05-31 2020-06-01

m = res['date'].gt(res['date_orig']) | (res['date_orig'].isnull() & res['date'].notnull())
res.loc[m, ['order_id', 'date']]
```

---

```
   order_id       date
0       123 2020-01-02
1       456 2021-01-01
2       789 2020-10-11
3       135 2020-06-01
```

Comment: This solution and the previous one by @wwbde work. thank you!